# Which libraries can be used for image caption generation?

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition, generative-model

Which libraries can be used for image caption generation?

Comment: I'd consider this "asking for a development tool", which is [off-topic](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This seems a bit broad; I assume you’re looking for libraries with “black box” models? I doubt you haven’t heard of TensorFlow / Keras and PyTorch. I’m sure you can find some implementations in these libraries on github. Also look into FastAI; I don’t know if they have a black box model already written (I don’t really use it often), but they are very good so long as you don’t need to know too much about what’s under the hood. FastAI is built on top of PyTorch (but it’s starting to now branch out to other frameworks).

Comment: You can try to go to this source: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/cin/2020/3062706/.

Answer (score 1):

Image Caption Generation is an interesting problem to work on. I think your question was to know if there are any open-source libraries with built-in functions for Image Captioning. You can build Image Caption Generation models using Frameworks like [**Tensorflow**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf), [**PyTorch**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html), and [**Trax**](https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/trax.html).

I'd also recommend you to read the following papers:

1. Show and Tell: A Neural Image Caption Generator. [Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4555)
2. Transfer learning from language models to image caption generators: Better models may not transfer better. [Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.01216)
3. Image Captioning with Unseen Objects. [Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00047)

Also, here are a couple of blog posts you can read:

- [How to Develop a Deep Learning Photo Caption Generator from Scratch](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-a-deep-learning-caption-generation-model-in-python/)
- [Learn to Build Image Caption Generator with CNN & LSTM](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-based-project-image-caption-generator-cnn/)
- [Image Captioning with Keras](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-captioning-with-keras-teaching-computers-to-describe-pictures-c88a46a311b8)

Answer (score 0):

I've been read from some blogs, for image caption generation you can use concepts of a CNN and LSTM model and build a working model of Image caption generator by implementing CNN with LSTM. I think before you want to make something and using this project, you need to have good knowledge of Deep learning, Python, working on Jupyter notebooks, Keras library, Numpy, and Natural language processing and make sure that you have installed all the following necessary libraries:
-pip install tensorflow
-keras
-pillow
-numpy
-tqdm
-jupyterlab

source : https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-based-project-image-caption-generator-cnn/